# Why $\operatorname{im} \delta_{-1}$ contains two functions and $f\in C^{0}(X, \mathbb{F}_2)$ is the characteristic function?

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In [the paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.1028), on page 21, line 15-20. It is said that $B^0=\operatorname{im} \delta_{-1}$ is the one dimensional space containing two functions and $f\in C^{0}(X, \mathbb{F}_2)$ is the characteristic function $\chi_A$ of some $A \subseteq X^{(0)}$? Here $X$ is a complex, $X^{(i)}$ is the set of simplices of $X$ of dimension $i$, $C^i(X, \mathbb{F}_2)$ is the $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space of the functions from $X^{(i)}$ to $\mathbb{F}_2$, $\delta_i: C^i(X, \mathbb{F}_2) \to C^{i+1}(X, \mathbb{F}_2)$ is given by 
$$
(\delta_i f)(F) = \sum_{G \in X^{(i)}} [F : G] f(G).
$$
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the definition of $[F:G]$ on page 20, for $i=-1$, $X^i = \{\emptyset \}$, $[v: \emptyset]=1$ since $F=\{v\}\backslash \emptyset = \{v_{j_0}\}$, $(-1)^0=1$. Therefore for $F \in X^{(0)}$, $(\delta_{-1}f)(F)=\sum_{G \in X^{(-1)}} [F:G]f(G) = f(\emptyset) \in \mathbb{F}_2$. Hence $(\delta_{-1}f)(F)$ is always $0$ or always $1$. That is $\delta_{-1}f$ is the zero function on $X^{(0)}$ or the constant function $1$ which is $1$ on every vertex of $X$.

For $f \in C^0(X, \mathbb{F}_2)$, $f: X^{(0)} \to \mathbb{F}_2$. Therefore $f(v) = 0$ or $1$ for $v \in X^{(0)}$. Hence $f = \chi_A$, where $A = \{v \in X^{(0)}: f(v)=1\} \subseteq X^{(0)}$.